# How to make 2 dictionary and group it twice

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am calculating totals per month for each country. I have managed to group data by country, but I get error

> An item with the same key has already been added.

when trying to put monthly totals into inner dictionary:

```
var totalPerMonth = data.AsEnumerable()
       .Select(x => new
       {
           Date = Convert.ToDateTime(x.ItemArray[0]).ToString("yyyy-MM"),
           Country = x.ItemArray[1],
           Revenue = x.ItemArray[2]
       })
       .GroupBy(x => x.Country)
       .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToDictionary(p => p.Date,////this is not unique/// p => Convert.ToDouble(p.Revenue)));
```

how to group it to make Date key unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `ToLookup` instead of `ToDictionary` to allow several values for same date.

Or you can use grouping to get unique dates only (assume you want to calculate totals for each month, so use `Sum` of revenue for each date group `dg` ):

```
var totalPerMonth = data.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new {
       Date = Convert.ToDateTime(x.ItemArray[0]).ToString("yyyy-MM"),
       Country = x.ItemArray[1],
       Revenue = Convert.ToDouble(x.ItemArray[2]) // convert here
     })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Country)
    .ToDictionary(
       g => g.Key,
       g => g.GroupBy(x => x.Date).ToDictionary(dg => dg.Key, dg => dg.Sum(x => x.Revenue))
    );
```

Comment: var totalPerMonth = data.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(
                    x =>
                        new
                        {
                            Date = Convert.ToDateTime(x.ItemArray[0]).ToString("yyyy-MM"),
                            Country = x.ItemArray[1],
                            Revenue = x.ItemArray[2]
                        }).GroupBy(x => x.Country).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.GroupBy(p=>p.Date).ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Sum(t=> Convert.ToDouble(t.Revenue))));

Comment: @Ekaterina yep, just was updating that after thinking about query variable name